# Working with XML in ActionScript

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've XML data in an other SWF file. I get the data through this:

```
var getXML = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("class");
var getXML = new getXML;
trace(getXML);
```

If I output the data, it's just the XML content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<assets>
   <asset name="blabla" />
    ....
</assets>
```

How can I "transform" this text into pure XML, so I could work with data.asset[0].@name?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate a XML object from the string output:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(getXML.toString());
```